# How to parse html string to JSX client side with variable and function call

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

```
html = "<p>Hello {this.getValue("a")}</p>"
```

Basically what I want to achieve is the value returned by the getValue() function once the html is rendered.

I tried react HTML parser however this shows the function name as it is written in the code.

I also tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML like below:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
```

The result with "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" is the same string

```
Hello {this.getValue("a")}
```

Also the string is from an api response

example: `"<div class="test"><span>Overview</span></div><p><b>testing testing</b></p><p>{this.getValue('a')}, testing</p>"`

Answer (score 2):

Use template literals - use backticks `` and `${}`:

```js
const getValue = arg => arg + arg;
const html = `<p>Hello ${getValue("a")}</p>`;
document.write(html);
```

Comment: Just to explain further:  the string that I am getting is from an api response, will it then be possible to use template literals and back ticks?

Comment: You could use `replace` to do that

Comment: Okay, lemme try that

Comment: I tried that however it's replacing all the other double quotes, the response from api is like this "<div class="test"><span>Overview</span></div><p><b>testing testing</b></p><p>{this.getValue('a')}, testing</p>"